# Keeping records of 7 days and delete the older records automatically in sqlite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a database in my android application where i keep records of  my employees with date of every day i want to keep just 7 days records and delete previous all records how can i do this? 
i am using this function in my DB.But this function delete data of current date and i get not data in DB.

```
  String query = " DELETE FROM RecordsTable WHERE Date <= date('now','-7 days') ";

    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    if (mCursor.getCount() == 0) {
        mCursor.close();
        return false;
    } else {
        mCursor.close();
        db.close();

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What does not work/ what is the bug?

Comment: it is deleting data of every day

Comment: date is in String format and i am closing db too.

Comment: `Date` (capital D) should be in date format to make this comparison work. Cast `Date` into date and it should work.

Comment: this Date is my column in table. Should i need to change "Date" into "date" ?

Comment: Using Date as string is not always safe in comparisons: Change to integer and use the integer style of date comparison.